# I want Android Bluetooth broadcasting, with less latency than ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY, close to the 10ms frequency of Apple's device development

Tags: android, bluetooth

As mentioned above，

```
   //Bluetooth configuration
    myAdvertiseSettings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()                
            .setAdvertiseMode(ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .setConnectable(false)
            .setTimeout(0)
            .setTxPowerLevel(ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH)
            .build();
```

Android, I know the lowest 100ms delay.
apple phone, I know the lowest 10ms delay.

Android delay is really too high.

The broadcasting efficiency is not high enough.
I want to implement 10ms's Bluetooth broadcasting delay like Apple device.

Please help solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: The actual delay that you will get will depend on your phone hardware, not just Android. What device(s) have you tried this on?

Comment: I can achieve 10ms Bluetooth broadcasting on Apple phone.

Comment: Android communication is too slow.